# Why not to tag the stateful attribute lazy?

Tags: elm

We can use [Html.Lazy.lazy](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/html/latest/Html-Lazy#lazy) to precisely tag the `stateful element`, but nothing like `Attribute.lazy` is avaialbe to tag the `stateful attribute`. What are the rationals behind this?

```
type alias Model =
    { text : String, color : String }


view model =
    div [ style "color" model.color ] 
        [ lazy text model.text ]
```

Answer (score 2):

After reading [Elm lazy guide](https://guide.elm-lang.org/optimization/lazy.html) again, I see it was my own misinterpretation about how [Html.Lazy](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/html/latest/Html-Lazy) really works. Below shows how to tag the model including the `stateful attribute`.

```
type alias Model =
    { txt : String, color : String }


viewStateful txt color =
    div [ style "color" color ]
        [ text txt ]


view model =
    lazy2 viewStateful model.txt model.color
```